# Doubts about beta function calculations in perturbative vs Wilsonian renormalisation

Tags: quantum-field-theory, renormalization, path-integral, effective-field-theory

Consider a field $\phi$ with action $S[\phi]$. Introduce a fundamental cutoff at energy $\Lambda_0$, and let $\Lambda$ be a much smaller energy scale characterising some process of interest. [Note: in some contexts, e.g. dimensional regularisation, my $\Lambda_0$ and $\Lambda$ are instead referred to as  $\frac{1}{\epsilon}$ and $\mu$.] In Wilsonian renormalisation, we define the effective action as
$$\tag{1} S_\text{eff}[\phi_-;\Lambda,\Lambda_0] \equiv -\log\int_{\Lambda}^{\Lambda_0} D\phi_+ e^{-S[\phi_-+\phi_+]}.$$

Renormalisation tells us how $S_\text{eff}$ changes as we lower or raise $\Lambda$, i.e. as we integrate out more or fewer modes. In particular, it tells us how the couplings, which I'll call $g(\Lambda,\Lambda_0)$, change. For some chosen $\Lambda_\text{ex}$, we can go out and experimentally measure the couplings $g(\Lambda_\text{ex},\Lambda_0)$. Then, to find  $g(\Lambda_\text{ex}-\delta\Lambda,\Lambda_0)$, we just have integrate out the shell of modes in $[\Lambda_\text{ex}-\delta\Lambda,\Lambda_\text{ex})$ (or run things in reverse, if $\delta\Lambda< 0$). This gives us the beta functions.

The result of integrating out this shell of modes is completely insensitive to the large-$\Lambda_0$ behaviour of the path integral. Indeed, $\Lambda_0$ is totally fixed throughout, and never appears in calculations once we've gone out and measured the couplings experimentally. Rather, everything is expressed in terms of measured, or at least measurable, physical quantities, and all the integrals we're ever required to do to make predictions are manifestly finite (IR issues aside).

This picture is quite clear and compelling to me, but I struggle to square it with the perturbative renormalisation picture.

Roughly speaking, to find the beta functions in perturbative renormalisation, we do some calculation to find the $\Lambda_0\to\infty$ behaviour of the couplings $g(\Lambda,\Lambda_0)$. There's supposedly a "divergent piece" $g_\text{div}(\Lambda,\Lambda_0)$, and we cancel this using a counterterm in the action. From this counterterm we somehow obtain the beta function, presumably by differentiating something (what?) with respect to $\Lambda$. I admit I get lost in the details here, but my overall worry is that we seem to *only* care about the UV behaviour of the path integral, throwing out any finite pieces along the way. This is in complete contrast to the Wilsonian picture, where we never cared about the $\Lambda_0\to\infty$ behaviour of anything.

So, my question: In perturbative renormalisation, why does the divergence behaviour of $g(\Lambda,\Lambda_0)$ as $\Lambda_0\to\infty$ allow us to compute the dependence of $g(\Lambda,\Lambda_0)$ on $\Lambda$? Why don't we need to keep track of the finite parts?

Comment: You only discard finite parts if you are using an MS-type scheme. There is nothing that makes one scheme privileged over another because we *cannot* "go out and experimentally measure the couplings". We measure a cross section. The formula that relates it to a coupling is scheme-dependent, cancelling the fact that the formula for the running of said coupling is also scheme-dependent.